# GMT+3 Timezone Outputs Incorrect Time

Tags: r, lubridate

In the lubridate package, when I use now(tzone = 'Etc/GMT+3') when my system defaults to UTC, I get a time that is 3 hours *behind* my current UTC time instead of ahead:

> now(tzone='Etc/GMT+3')
> [1] "2023-09-30 15:57:36 -03"

The time was 18:57 UTC when I attempted this, so I was expecting it to say 21:57 instead. Why is it taking away hours instead of adding them?

Comment: The current time plus the "+3" is the GMT time.  So if you are east of GMT, then use 'Etc/GMT-3'

Answer (score 1):

From `?timezones` :

> Most platforms support time zones of the form ‘⁠`Etc/GMT+n⁠`’ and
> ‘⁠`Etc/GMT-n`⁠’ (possibly also without prefix ‘⁠`Etc/⁠`’), which assume a
> fixed offset from UTC (hence no DST). Contrary to some expectations
> (but consistent with names such as ‘⁠`PST8PDT`⁠’), negative offsets are
> times ahead of (east of) UTC, **positive offsets are times behind (west
> of) UTC**.

So you are probably after `lubridate::now("Etc/GMT-3")`:

```r
lubridate::now("UTC")
#> [1] "2023-09-30 19:56:33 UTC"
lubridate::now("Etc/GMT-3")
#> [1] "2023-09-30 22:56:33 +03"
```